# SQL Server JOINS vs Subquerys

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, query, desempenho

Estava fazendo algumas consultas, e veio a necessidade de realizar o agrupamento de uma tabela que estava em um JOIN dentro da consulta. Para exemplificar.

**Tabela de vendas.**

```
+----+---------+------------+----------+
| Id | Cliente |    Data    | Vendedor |
+----+---------+------------+----------+
|  1 |     123 | 2018-03-20 |       12 |
|  2 |     456 | 2018-03-20 |       34 |
+----+---------+------------+----------+
```

Chave (Id)
**Itens das vendas:**

```
+-------+---------+------------+----------------+
| Venda | Produto | Quantidade | Valor_Unitario |
+-------+---------+------------+----------------+
|     1 |     123 |          3 |           5,50 |
|     1 |     456 |          9 |              5 |
|     2 |     789 |          5 |            7,0 |
|     2 |     101 |          7 |            7,0 |
+-------+---------+------------+----------------+
```

Chave (Venda, Produto)

A consulta que eu estava escrevendo era um JOIN simples.

```
SELECT * FROM vendas v INNER JOIN vendas_itens vi ON vi.Venda = v.Id
```

Porém, em determinado momento, quis saber quanto vale cada venda e as informações do pedido. Determinado a possuir tais informações, escrevi as duas consultas abaixo.

```
SELECT V.*, 
SUM(Quantidade * Valor_Unitario) AS [Total]
FROM vendas v 
LEFT JOIN vendas_itens vi 
ON vi.Venda = v.Id 
GROUP BY V.Id, 
         V.Cliente, 
         V.Data, 
         V.Vendedor
```

E

```
SELECT V.*,
       (SELECT SUM(Quantidade * Valor_Unitario) 
        FROM vendas_itens vi 
        WHERE vi.Venda = v.Id ) AS [Total]
FROM vendas v
```

Verifiquei o plano de execução de ambas as consultas, porém, houve apenas uma diferença.

[image: Plano de execução]

Gostaria de saber o seguinte:

-Qual a diferença de performance entre ambas as consultas?
Há alguma vantagem entre uma e outra (tirando o fato da segunda escrever menos)?
-  (Ainda sou júnior)Qual delas é mais "profissional"? Ou seria apenas questão de gosto?

Fiz alguns testes em uma tabela com 15k registros e não vi diferença na performance.

Qualquer melhoria na pergunta, só comentar, por favor.

**EDIT1:** Como bem lembrado pelo José, a primeira consulta deve ser LEFT, pois, a subquery não irá limitar o escopo da primeira tabela. E como ele perguntou, não há índices nas tabelas, apenas as chaves.

Comment: Parabéns por se preocupar em analisar o plano de execução de cada consulta. // A semelhança nos dois planos de execução deve-se à ação do otimizador de consultas do SQL Server. // Para comparar os 2 códigos, sugiro que altere o primeiro código para LEFT JOIN. Isto fica mais próximo da subconsulta correlacionada que utilizou, que internamente é transformada em OUTER JOIN.  // Poderia acrescentar na descrição do tópico quais são os índices de cada tabela?

Comment: @JoséDiz, pronto, fiz a alteração na pergunta. Agradeço a "divulgação" deste otimizador de consultas do SQL Server,  vou procurar mais sobre ele.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu utilizaria o primeiro, eu sei que não é regra e que depende muito da quantidade de registros, além de outras coisas, mas em muitos casos utilizar sub-queries torna a consulta um pouco menos performática.

Comment: Olhe os planos de execução que vieram junto à pergunta. Como você pode dizer **nesse caso** que a performance foi afetada?

Comment: Boa parte dos Compute Scalar estão setadas como 0%, mas esse é o valor arredondado aproximado, não tem como ele 'custar' exatamente 0,000%, na segunda consulta existe um Compute Scalar a mais que na minha opinião é desnecessário, não tem pra que deixar o caminho com uma etapa a mais, por mais que nesse caso a diferença não vai ser visível para a nossa percepção, podendo utilizar qualquer um dos dois sem afetar o resultado final, mas eu optaria por utilizar o caminho "mais curto", nota 10 por ele ser tão cuidadoso.

Comment: Bem, você tocou num ponto importante. Realmente há uma etapa a mais, mas como outras etapas desse processo ela não consegue ter uma representação significativa de custo. Inclusive, é bem capaz de ela ser maior do que as outras duas. Por quê? Pela precisão. Talvez as duas etapas de 0% sejam 0,0001%, mas a etapa única seja de 0,0003%. Jamais saberemos a verdade porque o software não tem precisão o suficiente.

Comment: O ideal seria um software de precisão que mostrasse os milissegundos do tempo total de execução em várias casas decimais, aqui na empresa onde eu trabalho tem, mas ele é específico para as tecnologias que a empresa utiliza, não teria como utilizar fora, mas é extremamente útil.